# Can we execute select statement in AND conditon (getting error missing expression)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am building a complex query. First here is my query

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No." 
from losa_app LOSA_APP, 
     losa_app_z LOSA_APP_Z
where 
    LOSA_APP.app_status='A' 
and 
    trunc(sysdate) between (nvl(LOSA_APP_Z.li_dt, LOSA_APP_Z.li_collect_dt)) AND ((trunc(sysdate))) 
and
    (trunc(sysdate) - nvl(losa_app_z.li_dt,losa_app_z.li_collect_dt)) > 90  
and
    (select losa_app_z.app_ref_no 
     from losa_app_z 
     where (trunc(sysdate) - nvl(losa_app_z.li_dt, losa_app_z.li_collect_dt)) > 90
    )
```

The problem is if i run the last query separately or i omit the last query then it is run fine, like if i only run

```
 (select losa_app_z.app_ref_no 
  from losa_app_z 
  where (trunc(sysdate) - nvl(losa_app_z.li_dt, losa_app_z.li_collect_dt)) > 90)
```

but if i run the whole query then i get the error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 128
```

Line 7 is the line at which my last query `and
    (select losa_app_z.app_ref_no from losa_app_z....` is present. What i am doing wrong ? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare result of this query

```
 and
 (select losa_app_z.app_ref_no 
  from losa_app_z 
  where (trunc(sysdate) - nvl(losa_app_z.li_dt, losa_app_z.li_collect_dt)) > 90
 ) = something_here
```

to something.

For future always try to manage your brackets properly. Count them if necessary.